# Using a functions argument to find and objects key value pair?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm trying to find a key value pair value but i want to pass the key in as an argument but it isn't seeming to work.

```
function drawPieChart(){  

var findData = function(variable){
    return dailyLog.find({createdBy: Meteor.user().username}, {fields: {variable: 1}}).fetch()[0].variable;
};

var data = [
    {
        value: findData(adherence),
        color: "#CBDDE7"
    }...
```

I want variable to be passed in twice, once to sort and other to find the value but it is actually looking for the key value pair "variable" which obviously doesn't exist.

How do i make it be seen as the argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two aspects to this:

1. Creating the fields object with a property whose name is the value of `variable` rather than the literal name `variable`, and
2. Accessing the resulting field based on the value of the variable (rather than the literal name `variable`)

Dealing with #2 first because it's easier: In JavaScript, you can access a property on an object either using dot notation and a property name literal (`obj.foo`), or using brackets notation and a property name *string** (`obj["foo"]`). In the latter case, the string can be the result of any expression, including a variable lookup. So if `variable` contains `"foo"`, then `obj[variable]` will get or set the `foo` property on `obj`.

Back to #1: For now, you have to create the object you're going to pass as `fields` first and then assign the property value via brackets notation rather than in an object initializer:

```
    var fields = {};
    fields[variable] = 1;
```

If `variable` contains `"foo"`, then `fields[variable] = 1` sets the `foo` property on `fields` to `1`.

So putting that all together:

```
var findData = function(variable){
    var fields = {};
    fields[variable] = 1;
    return dailyLog.find({createdBy: Meteor.user().username}, {fields: fields}).fetch()[0][variable];
    // Note ------------------------------------------------------------------------------^--------^
};
```

---

In the next version of JavaScript, ECMAScript6 (aka ES6), you'll be able to do #1 with a "computed property name" in the object initializer (and still retrieve it with brackets notation). Perhaps unsurprisingly, computed property names use...brackets!

```
// ES6 only!!
var findData = function(variable){
    return dailyLog.find({createdBy: Meteor.user().username}, {fields: {[variable]: 1}}).fetch()[0].[variable];
    // Note ------------------------------------------------------------^--------^ --- and ---------^--------^
};
```

---

* Side note: In ES6, brackets notation can be used with things called `Symbols` as well as strings. It's not relevant to your question, but I said "string" above, and soon that won't be true, so...

Comment: +1 for this. If you don't know the property you're going to call in an object in advance, say if it's a parameter from a method, you need to use the bracket `[variable]` notation instead of the dot `.variable` notation.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder dude, thanks so much! Solved it perfectly and I'm so happy, works perfectly!! Thank you!!